# How to accept multiple input into a same script

Tags: bash, unix

How can I accept multiple-line input into a same script. Or in other words to process multiple files with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter file names (wild cards OK)'
read input_source
if test -f "$input_source"
then 
sort $var | uniq -c | head -10
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter file names (wild cards OK)'
read files
for input_source in $files ; do
    if test -f "$input_source" ; then 
        sort $var | uniq -c | head -10  # You probably should include $input_source somewhere
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks! And if I want to repeat the sort $input_source | uniq -c | head -10    for the input files  over and over until the user indicates end-of-file. This is done by entering the single character Ctrl-d as a file name. Any ideas ??

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop:

```
while read input_source 
do
# Do something with $input_source
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cat all the files that match the input pattern-:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter file names (wild cards OK)'
read input_source
cat $input_source | sort | uniq -c | head -10
```